# Why is the wrong dependency version imported when importing 2 BOMs with test dependencies

Tags: java, maven

I have 2 projects, project A and project B which each import the testcontainer-bom, but with different versions, in their parent pom.xml:

project A:

```
...
    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
        <module>module2</module>
        <module>projecta-bom</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        ...
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.16.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
...
```

and the modules are the following:

module1:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>projecta-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TESTS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-params</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

module2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>projecta-parent</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
          <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
          <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

and

projecta-bom:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
                <artifactId>module1</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
                <artifactId>module2</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    <dependencyManagement>
```

project B:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.projecta</groupId>
                <artifactId>projecta-bom</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.3</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        <dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
```

When I build projectB, i end up with testcontainers:jdbc and testcontainers:postgresql versions 1.16.3. I understand that if the same artifact is defined with different versions in 2 imported BOMs, then the version in the BOM file that was declared first will win, but its not clear to me why the testcontainer dependencies from projectA are being imported in the first place, given that they have a test scope.

Am I doing something wrong? or am I misunderstanding how dependency scopes and BOMs work?

edit: to be more specific, why are dependencies with test from being pulled in from projecta-bom?

maven version: 3.8.4
java version: 17.0.7

Comment: Define the testcontainers-bom before the bom of projecta-bom...

Comment: I know that i can change the order of my imports. i edited my post to ask the more specific question: why are dependencies with <scope>test</scope> from being pulled in from projecta-bom?

Comment: Also can you show the full poms for module1 and module2...

Comment: Updated pom.xml for module1 and module2. Updated module2 to be more representative of what our real poms look like.

Comment: @Wonger I understand that you need to "shorten" the BOMs/POMs, but I guess you missed something somewhere. The BOMs/POMs in the question seem fine.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, I'm not sure what you mean by "the boms / poms look fine". Are you saying that that, based on the poms i provided, the `projecta-bom` import is expected to bring the testcontainer dependencies from projectA as transitive dependencies? Even though they have `<scope>test</scope>`?

Comment: @Wonger I mean that from the XML you provided, you should get version `1.18.3`

Comment: Can you provide an example project on github or alike?